# How to set LG Gram Num Lock key to automatically be ON when it boots?

Tags: lg-gram

Does anyone know how to set the Num Lock in my LG Gram to automatically be ON when it boots up?

My LG Gram:

Device name    xxx
Full device name   xxxProcessor   
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz   1.50 GHz
Installed RAM    40.0 GB (39.7 GB usable)
Device ID    52D5542C-5CEC-4C66-B175-8E484BE67AA5
Product ID    00330-75074-33277-AAOEMSystem type    64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch    No pen or touch input is available for this display
Edition    Windows 10 Pro
Version    22H2
Installed on    ‎12/‎7/‎2019
OS build    19045.3086
Experience    Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

Is there a BIOS setting --or something/somewhere else-- to set the Num Lock in my LG Gram to automatically be ON when it boots up?Thanks!

Comment: This post might help ..... https://superuser.com/questions/1678324/how-can-i-toggle-the-fn-key-lock-on-an-lg-gram-running-linux    (.1%)   ......  It might possibly provide some ideas for you.